# pandas merge not working left_on, right_on method

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to change a column heading but pandas won't let me. It has changed one of the columns I asked, but not the other.

```
new_df2 = new_df2.rename(columns={'value': 'Euro to Dollar rate','date':'exchange rate date'})
```

output:

```
    exchange rate date  value
0   2020-12-31  1.2216
1   2020-12-31  1.2216
2   2020-12-31  1.2216
3   2020-12-31  1.2216
4   NaT     NaN
```

Goal is to change 'value' column to 'Euro to Dollar rate'

Comment: what is `print (new_df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: `'exchange rate date', ' value']` - pesky space character. Removed it and it worked. Thanks for your help! Spent 15 minutes trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

`print (new_df2.columns.tolist())` returns:`'exchange rate date', ' value']`

This resulted in me spotting the space character in 'value'. Removed it and it works.